# Setup automatic product redirect once out of stock on M1

Tags: magento-1.9, 301-redirect

Is there an **extension/module** for **M1 Enterprise** that will manage **redirects to a suitable category page** once a **product is out of stock** and won't come back into stock?

Comment: Don't know about the extension. But how you manage category URL? in product level or in the config? Write more will help easily.

Comment: Categories are managed through the catalog then assigned to relevant item n the product setup.